# Monte Carlo simulation for the quantum oscillator in the path integral approach

Tags: python, computational-physics, integration, monte-carlo, quantum-mechanics

## The theory

Consider a quantum harmonic oscillator described by the potential $V(q)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2$. In the path integral formulation, the partition function can be written as $$Z\propto\int Dx(\tau)\exp\left(-\frac{S_E}{\hbar}\right) $$ where $\tau$ is Euclidean time and $S_E$ is the Euclidean action for closed paths $$S_E=\int_0^{\beta \hbar}d\tau\left(\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2(\tau)+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2(\tau)\right).$$

To attack this problem numerically, we can make this quantity discrete by choosing a sequence of  $N$ points $x_1,...,x_N$ on the path $x(\tau)$ with distance $a$ between each other; rescaling these variables as $x_j=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}y_j$ we can write
$$\frac{S_E^{discrete}}{\hbar}=\sum_{j=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{2\eta}(y_{j+1}-y_j)^2+\frac{\eta}{2}y_j^2\right) $$ where $\eta=a\omega$. The continuum is then recovered in the limit $\eta\to 0$.
In this discrete form, the internal energy of the system transforms as follows: $$\frac{U^{cont}}{\hbar\omega}=\partial_\beta\log Z=\hbar\omega\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{e^{N\eta}-1}\right) \  \Rightarrow \  \frac{U^{discrete}}{\hbar\omega}=\frac{1}{2\eta}-\frac{1}{2\eta^2}\langle \Delta y^2\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle y^2\rangle$$ where $y^2, \Delta y^2=(y_{j+1}-y_j)^2$ are first calculated as averages over a single path, and the averages $\langle y^2\rangle, \langle\Delta y^2\rangle$ are taken over many paths distributed according to the function $$p(y_1,...,y_N)=e^{-S_E^{discrete}/\hbar}.$$

## The algorithm

In order to sample paths that follow this distribution, we can employ a MCMC method based on the Metropolis algorithm:

> 1. Initialize the discrete path in a cold configuration (all zeros) or hot configuration (random numbers)
> 2. For each Monte Carlo sweep, loop on all $j=1,...,N$ and propose to modify $y_j$ with a uniformly sampled $y_p\leftarrow [y_j-\delta,y_j+\delta]$ for some parameter $\delta$.
> 3. The update is accepted with probability $r=\min\left(1,e^{-\Delta S_{E}^{discrete}}\right)$, where
>    \begin{align*}
>    \Delta S_{E}^{discrete}&=(y^p)^2\left(\frac{\eta}{2}+\frac{1}{\eta}\right)-\frac{y^p}{\eta}(y_{j_0+1}+y_{j_0-1})-y_{j_0}^2\left(\frac{\eta}{2}+\frac{1}{\eta}\right)\\&-\frac{1}{2}y_{j_0}(y_{j_0+1}+y_{j_0-1}).
>    \end{align*}

## The code

Here is my implementation of the algorithm in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import random as rand
import time as tm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#STRAIGHT-LINE INITIALIZATION
def cold_path(N):

    return np.zeros(N)

#RANDOM PATH INITIALIZATION
def hot_path(N):
    
    return np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)
    
#MONTE CARLO SIMULATION
def Metropolis_HO(start,N,eta,delta,ntimes):
       
    #Set path at initial step
    if start=='cold':
        path=cold_path(N)
        
    elif start=='hot':
        path=hot_path(N)
      
    else: 
        raise Exception('Choose either hot or cold starting path configuration.')
    
    #Initialize arrays of observables
    y_squared=np.zeros(ntimes)
    delta_y_squared=np.zeros(ntimes)
    
    #Useful constants
    c1=1./eta
    c2=1./eta+eta/2.
    
    #Iterate loop on all sites
    for i in range(ntimes):
        for j in range(N):

            #Set y as j-th point on path
            y=path[j]

            #Proposed modification
            y_p=rand.uniform(y-delta,y+delta)
            
            #Calculate accept probability
            force=path[(j+1)%N]+path[(j-1)%N]
            p_ratio=c1*y_p*force-c2*(y_p*y_p)-c1*y*force+c2*(y*y)
            
            #Accept-reject
            if rand.random()<np.exp(p_ratio):
                path[j]=y_p
        
        #Average of y^2 on the path
        temp=0.
        for k in range(N):
            temp+=path[k]**2
        y_squared[i]=temp/N
        #pos_squared[i]=np.average(path**2)
        
        #Average of Delta y^2 on the path
        temp=0.
        for k in range(N):
            temp+=(path[k]-path[(k+1)%N])**2
        delta_y_squared[i]=temp/N
    
    #Get rid of non-equilibrium states and decorrelate
    n_corr=1
    n_term=10000
    
    y_squared=y_squared[n_term:ntimes:n_corr]
    delta_y_squared=delta_y_squared[n_term:ntimes:n_corr]
    
    return y_squared, delta_y_squared

#MONTE CARLO INTERNAL ENERGY
def U(y_squared,delta_y_squared,eta):
    
    c1=1./(2*eta)
    c2=1./(2*eta**2)
    
    av1=np.average(y_squared)
    av2=np.average(delta_y_squared)
    
    return c1-c2*av2+av1/2.

#THEORETICAL EXPECTATION FOR THE INTERNAL ENERGY
def exact_U(N,eta):
    
    return 0.5+1./(np.exp(N*eta)-1)
```

## The issue

To test the code above, I have fixed $\eta$ and calculated the internal energy for various values of $N$, comparing it with the exact version. This is the code to reproduce my results, and the graph obtained:

```
###-PARAMETERS-###
start_path='cold'
ntimes=50000
eta=0.01
delta=np.sqrt(eta)

Nmin=1
Nmax=10

N_array=np.arange(Nmin,Nmax,1)
U_array=[]

start=tm.time()
for N in N_array:
    
    #Run Metropolis with each N and fixed eta
    y_squared, delta_y_squared=Metropolis_HO(start_path,N,eta,delta,ntimes)
    
    #Calculate and store the internal energy)
    U_array.append(U(y_squared,delta_y_squared,eta))

plt.plot(N_array,U_array,linestyle='None',marker='s',color='k')

N_array=np.arange(0.1,Nmax,0.1)
exact_U_array=[]
for N in N_array:
    
    #Calculate theoretical energy
    exact_U_array.append(exact_U(N,eta))

plt.plot(N_array,exact_U_array,'b')
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.show()

end=tm.time()
print(f"Time taken: {end-start}.")
```

[image]

At $\eta=0.01$, I should be expecting the data to fit the theoretical curve much better. How may I improve the code to get better results?